# Re-writing URLs with an ending forward slash

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a quick question about re-writing urls. I would like all my pages to be re-written as such

```
mysite.com/edit.php -> mysite.com/edit/
mysite.com/search.php -> mysite.com/search/
```

Along with that it should still be able to take parameters

```
mysite.com/edit.php -> mysite.com/edit/?id=2
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't take the ending `/` so it's just `mysite.com/edit`

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Also, as an extra, is it possible to not allow users to actually add the `.php` if they tried to? So for example if I had `/edit.php` and I got it working to do `/edit/` or `/edit` and a user actually tried to type in `/edit.php` it wouldn't work.

Comment: Not sure off hand why the slash isn't accepted, but for the second part, you could add a rewrite rule to catch URLs that end in `.php` (with whatever other conditions you want) and do a 404 redirect. If I recall correctly, it's something like `[R=404]` in the flags.